# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo'

Tags: c#, reflection

I have several entities that I'd like to transform. Here is an example:

```
 public class FromClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

public class ToClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

I've made a class of how the transformation should be done for each property like this:

```
  public interface ITransformationRule
    {
        T Transform<T>(string value);
    }
    public class ColumnDescription
    {
        public string SourceColumnName { get; set; }
        public string TargetObjectProperty { get; set; }
        public ITransformationRule TransformationRule { get; set; }
    }
```

The source properties are always strings and the data is validated in a previous step so I know I can cast without exceptions. So for each property I have a transformationrules. Some transformations are plain casts while other do lookup in tables.

In the above example I'd have a List of ColumnDescriptions like this:

```
 public List<ColumnDescription> TransformationDescription = new List<ColumnDescription>
    {
        new ColumnDescription{SourceColumnName = "Id", TargetObjectProperty = "Id", TransformationRule = new IntegerTransformation() }

    };
```

etc... Now here is where I'm lost (or perhaps the ITransformationRule interface should look a little bit different). I've written the IntegerTransformationClass like this:

```
  public class IntegerTransformation : ITransformationRule
    {
        public T Transform<T>(string value)
        {
            object returnvalue = int.Parse(value);
            return (T) returnvalue;
        }
    }
```

finally I'm looping through the properties in the list like this:

```
foreach (var row in TransformationDescription)
        {
            ¨...
            var classType = row.TransformationRule.GetType();
            var methodInfo = classType.GetMethod("Transform");
            var generic = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(toProp.GetType());
            var parameters = new object[] { toProp.ToString() };
            var toValue = generic.Invoke(specialTransform.TransformationRule, parameters);
            toProp.SetValue(toObj, Convert.ChangeType(toValue, toProp.PropertyType), null);
        }
```

At runtime a get the exeption.Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' when returning from the TransformationClass.

Perhaps I'm going about the problem in a totaly wrong way. Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
var generic = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(toProp.GetType());
```

You're calling `GetType()` on `toProp` - that will return some type derived from `PropertyInfo`. You *actually* want the property type, so just change it to:

```
var generic = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(toProp.PropertyType);
```